# How to set default selected option in very big select tag with many options in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, select, view, controller, tags

I have 3 select tags with a lot of options inside them. One for year, one for month and one for day.
The question is ... How to set selected on the option I want.
I was thinking of this solutions:

1. Pass the options as array to the view. After that forech them in the select tag and with "@if" check every single one if its the right one and set "selected:selected".
   But in my case this isnt good solution because I have many options ... that means the array will be very very big.
2. Put if statement in every option in the html and check if its te right one and set  "selected:selected" to that option.  This is also a bad solution ... there will be like 200+ if statements.
3. Maybe create 3 db tables with this options inside. Getting them in the controller method, foreaching them in the select tag and checking them with if statement and setting "selected" to the right one.

I really dont know if Im thinking in the right way. I will apriciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

what you r doing is right here is a solution that it did worked for me, i have a user city, and when i want the user to update the city i show it as selected

just pass the arrays to the view then :

```
@foreach ($citys as $city)
@if (Auth::user()->city_id == $city->id)
<option value="{{$city->id}}" selected="selected">{{$city->name}}</option>
@else
<option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->name}}</option>
@endif
@endforeach
```

here is a short version u can use

```
@foreach ($citys as $city)
<option value="{{$city->id}}" @if (Auth::user()->city_id == $city->id) selected="selected" @endif > {{$city->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```